# The Animal Catchers

Tags: wordplay, story

*Using subtle context clues, try to figure out where the animal catchers are and what they are searching for.*

In a massive, massive desert - one of the biggest in the world - I trudged through the harsh landscape in search for a bear... could I do the trick? I know they're quick (hey, that rhymes!) around here, but I think I could find it.

In a massive, massive rainforest - the largest, in fact - I trudged through the harsh landscape in search for a frog... definitely not a dog. I ducked through the bog (hey, that rhymes!) but found nothing. The rain made everything glisten, like glass. I think I could find it.

I found it! I found the bear! **Hint:**

> What a dazzling coat. So clean and beautiful.

I found it! I found the frog! **Hint:**

> I can see *through it*. That is a little strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because I couldn't find anything deeper than the surface reading of the stories, I'll guess that the first catchers are looking for

> A polar bear

And they're looking in

> Antarctica, which is technically a desert, and the only one that I can think of that might have a bear in it. But, after a quick web search, there are no polar bears there; they're just in northern regions.

Meanwhile, the second catchers are looking for

> A glass frog

And they're looking in

> The Amazon, which is definitely the largest rainforest in the world. It also does contain glass frogs, according to another quick web search.